# sass / scss full site template(s)

Tags: ruby, css, sass

Is there a any full layout sass / scss templates / mixins like you get with compass but for a full site ?

so you can for example say 2 columns, width, color etc and creates a site / template ?

thanks
Rick

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are some starters:

http://www.blueprintcss.org/

http://960.gs/

There are lots more in this grain, and in fact, I believe Blueprint actually uses the 960 grid system as a base. This won't "create" a template for you, in the sense that it will make your graphics, but it will generate everything you need to lay down a solid CSS base for your site.

Past that, if you need a template that you can convert to a SASS/Ruby/Whatever project, I would recommend these two very high quality template sites for Joomla/Wordpress (which can be converted with reasonably minimal effort):

http://demo.yootheme.com (their "Warp" architecture is based on 960gs)

http://demo.rocketheme.com

Answer (score 0):

There are lots more in this grain, and in fact, I believe Blueprint actually uses the 960 grid system as a base. This won't "create" a template for you, in the sense that it will make your graphics, but it will generate everything you need to lay down a solid CSS base for your site.

Past that, if you need a template that you can convert to a SASS/Ruby/Whatever project, I would recommend these two very high quality template sites for Joomla/Wordpress (which can be converted with reasonably minimal effort):